# Pass Ansible parameters to include_role

Tags: ansible

I have a role that contains this task:

```
- name: Download something via Git
  include_role:
    name: git_cached
  vars:
    params:
      repo: https://somerepo
      dest: /some/path
```

I would really like to then have the git_cached role look like this:

```
- git: {{ params }}
```

I don't want to have to duplicate all of the parameters like this:

```
- git:
    repo: "{{ repo }}"
    dest: "{{ dest }}"
```

Because then, I have to do it for all the parameters, even the ones I don't typically use. I just want to basically "override" certain parameters that I pass into the include_role task.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: FWIW, see [example](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-lib/blob/master/tasks/al_git_checkout.yml)

Comment: Vladimir, could you briefly explain how you think the example you posted helps in this case? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! It's out of the scope if it's not self-explaining.

Answer (score 3):

Q: **"*Override certain parameters that pass them into the include_role task.*"**

A: The parameter [*tasks_from*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#parameter-tasks_from) serves this use-case. For example, create the task file

```yaml
shell> cat roles/git_cached/tasks/git.yml
- git:
    repo: "{{ params.repo }}"
    dest: "{{ params.dest }}"
    recursive: "{{ params.recursive|default(ommit) }}"
    depth: "{{ params.depth|default('1') }}"
```

Then "call" this task

```yaml
    - name: Download something via Git
      include_role:
        name: git_cached
        tasks_from: git.yml
      vars:
        params:
          repo: https://somerepo
          dest: /some/path
```

You might want to complete the task with all [git](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html#ansible-builtin-git-deploy-software-or-files-from-git-checkouts) parameters:

- The parameters *repo* and *dest* are required.
- In some parameters, like *recursive*, the default values are defined. You can either omit the parameter, in which case the default value will be used, or define your own default.
- Some parameters, like *depth*, don't have defaults.  Also here you can either omit the parameter, in which case the parameter won't be used or define your own default.
- It's a good idea to "namespace" the variables.
- It's a good idea to put the default variables into roles/git_cached/defaults/main.yml

Comment: How is what you're suggesting different than leaving off the "tasks_from" entirely? Because it looks a lot like what I'm trying to avoid (duplicating all of the git parameters with default(omit)).

Comment: Imagine the role is a dynamic library. "task_from" calls a single function (task) and not the whole library (role). You write the library (role) with the functions (tasks) once and then you call the functions (include role tasks_from).

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation!